# My sed command won't execute a rename of fastq.gz files using a .txt file as a reference, but will show me a desirable output

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I am looking to write some code using dummy samples that will look at a confusing fastq.gz filename and rename it based on it's corresponding simple sample ID from a .txt file that contains both. I will eventually do this in one pass for hundreds of files so I want to dial it in on something small and lowrisk. I have written some empty txt files to pose as my fastq.gz filenames. The reference .txt file contains both sequence and sample IDs. I want to read the sequence ID's find a match and edit the file name in my dummy file to match the corresponding Sample ID

An example of a line from my .txt file:

`52704.3.422276.TTGCGAAG-TTGCGAAG.fastq.gz  S19_BESC 156_B1_d1`

I have written code that shows a rename, but when I add the 'e' flag to it, it does nothing or it tells me `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:`m'`

I have written:
`sed 's/\(\w+\.fastq\.gz\)/${SeqID%.fastq.gz} ${SampleID}/' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`

To give me a desirable output of:

```
52704.3.422276.TTGCGAAG-TTGCGAAG.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d1
52704.3.422276.ACATAGGC-ACATAGGC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d3
52704.3.422276.GTTGTAGC-GTTGTAGC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d6
52704.3.422276.ACCACGAT-ACCACGAT.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d9
52704.3.422276.CTGAAGCT-CTGAAGCT.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d12
52704.3.422276.TCCTTAGC-TCCTTAGC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B1_d15
52704.3.422276.ACGACTTG-ACGACTTG.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d1
52704.3.422276.TGCTTCCA-TGCTTCCA.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d3
52704.3.422276.GCATACAG-GCATACAG.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d6
52704.3.422276.CTTCGTTC-CTTCGTTC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d9
52704.3.422276.TGCGAACT-TGCGAACT.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d12
52704.3.422276.CATCGTGA-CATCGTGA.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B2_d15
52704.3.422276.TCTCCGAT-TCTCCGAT.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d1
52704.3.422276.AGAGTAGC-AGAGTAGC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d3
52704.3.422276.CAACACCT-CAACACCT.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d6
52704.3.422276.TTGTGTGC-TTGTGTGC.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d9
52709.1.423639.ACTGCTAG-ACTGCTAG.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d12
52709.1.423639.GTCATCGA-GTCATCGA.fastq.gz       S19_BESC 156_B3_d15
```

But when I add the 'e' flag:

`sed -e 's/\(\w+\.fastq\.gz\)/${SeqID%.fastq.gz} ${SampleID}/' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`

I get nothing. Or if I do this:

`sed 's/\(\w+\.fastq\.gz\)/${SeqID%.fastq.gz} ${SampleID}/' -e 'mv $1 $2' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`

I get:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:` m'`

Thank you in advance this type of code really gets me hung up.

Comment: A concrete example of what you are trying to do would be useful.  Given the  line `52704.3.422276.TTGCGAAG-TTGCGAAG.fastq.gz  S19_BESC 156_B1_d1` what *exactly* do you want to be the new name of the file `52704.3.422276.TTGCGAAG-TTGCGAAG.fastq.gz`.

Comment: @pjh In this case I would want to rename 52704.3.422276.TTGCGAAG-TTGCGAAG.fastq.gz to S19_BESC 156_B1_d1.fastq.gz. I am pursuing this because downstream scripts I'm using have trouble working through the long decimal filled orignal file name. It also will increase the ease of deciphering results. Does this answer your question better? Thanks

Comment: If you're using `${SampleID}` as a shell environment variable AND you want the value of that variable substituted into your file, you need to "expose" the value to the shell by using dbl-quotes to surround your `sed` command, not single quotes, i.e. `sed "s/.../..${SampleID}/" file` . Same with `${SeqID}`. . Good luck.

Comment: I feel that using `sed` for this task is a bit of an overkill. I don't understand the full process: You have somewhere a text file (where you present here one line as an example), and out of this, you want to infer how certain files are renamed. This looks a bit like a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @user1934428 sed is perfectly fine to construct command lines from a stream of input and shell them out.  The two methods are using `e commandline` or `s/string/substitution/e` where "substitution" is sent to the shell.  OP seems to be confusing that with sed commandline option `-e` which means "run this sed command with sed."

Answer (score 3):

I would simply do it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
while read -r f1 f2 f3; do
    echo mv "$f1" "$f2 $f3.fastq.gz"
done < BESC-156_Swaps.txt
```

It just prints command lines as a dry-run. If the output looks good, drop `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're doing, but to use `s///e` you need to substitute in a commandline command.   You're missing `mv`:

`sed 's/\(\w+\.fastq\.gz\)/mv ${SeqID%.fastq.gz} ${SampleID}/e' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`

`s///e` will execute the commandline in the pattern buffer after the substitution.  You need the mv, or echo to be in there.   (the way to dry-run your `mv` is to replace the `mv` with `echo`.)

`-e 'mv file1 file2'` is also missing the sed command `e`.   Would have to be `-e 'e mv file1 file2'`   `-e` the commandline option and `e` the sed command are not the same.

Update:

@WalterA points out that the `${}` shell variable are gibberish here.  Because they're within single quotes, they'd appear as literally that.   I had taken the OP at word that the match was "working" and assumed that the execution was not.   However the OP could just as well have used `cat BESC-156_Swaps.txt` to get same output because the match was never matching (`\w+` would not work with basic regular expression).

So, looking deeper here, we basically want to turn each line into `mv`.  That is this, AFAICT:

```
sed 's/^/mv /e' BESC-156_Swaps.txt
```

... just insert `mv`  at start of line (`^`) and execute in shell.

Or, assuming there should be three fields and a space in the resulting filename:

```
sed 's/(.*) (.* .*)/mv \1 "\2.fastq.gz"/e' BESC-156_Swaps.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Are you suggesting I reformat my code like this? 'sed 's/\(\w+\.fastq\.gz\)/mv ${SeqID%.fastq.gz} ${SampleID}/' -e 'e mv $1 $2' BESC-156_Swaps.txt' I did this and when I ran it I get 'mv: missing file operand' From the manual it looks like specifying the input and output files with the -v flag is what I should do? I don't know exactly how I'd format this. Not sure if this the exact route but I know I need to specify a destination somehow. Thanks again

Comment: No.  I added a `mv` to your `s///e`.  The error message you get is because you are only passing two files to the commandline.   `file1 file2` doesn't do a `mv` unless you add `mv`

Comment: I agree that the "option" `e` should be after the last slash. I don't understand why you use variables in the command. I think this should work: `sed -r 's/([^ ]*\.fastq\.gz)[ ]*(.*)/echo mv "\1" "\2" /e'` (remove the word echo when output looks fine).
However, also consider the solution of @tshiono, which is faster and easier to understand.

Comment: @WalterA - honestly I thought something was being pasted in from a shell script and was trying to help on some `e` nuances.   I missed some of the broader misunderstandings that I see now.  Like the fact that those bash-like variables are used within single quotes... but nonetheless user thought it was working.  My guess is the match didn't match, so the same desirable output would come from `cat`.

Comment: @WalterA:  Updated with `sed 's/^/mv /e' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`

Comment: `mv a b c` will not move `a` to `"b c"`, you need to but quotes before the second and after the third word. Also add `fastq.gz` and find something like `sed -r 's/(.*) (.*) (.*)/mv "\1" "\2 \3.fastq.gz"/e' BESC-156_Swaps.txt`.

Comment: @WalterA  Sorry I probably seem flippant.   I am more trying to be 'useful' than write the code.  Assuming that is what's wanted seems like a leap, but yeah, you can do that, if it's what the OP intends.   Was wondering why other answer assumed three fields and a space in the resulting file name.   Yes.  `'s/(.*) (.* .*)/mv \1 "\2.fastq.gz"/e' ` ... etc.